# How to know how long it takes to create a pod in Kubernetes ? Is there any command please?

Tags: kubernetes

I have my Kubernetes cluster and I need to know how long it takes to create a pod? Is there any Kubernetes command show me that ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you already tried?  This isn't substantially different from timing anything else.

Comment: @DavidMaze. I just want to know what is the time needs to create a pod in my machine. when I create pods using "kubectl create -f pod.yaml" I want to know to long it take to make the pod up and running. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

What you are asking for is not existing.

I think you should first understand the [Pod Overview](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-overview/).

> A  *Pod*  is the basic building block of Kubernetes–the smallest and simplest unit in the Kubernetes object model that you create or deploy. A Pod represents a running process on your cluster.
>
> A Pod encapsulates an application container (or, in some cases, multiple containers), storage resources, a unique network IP, and options that govern how the container(s) should run. A Pod represents a unit of deployment:  *a single instance of an application in Kubernetes*, which might consist of either a single container or a small number of containers that are tightly coupled and that share resources.

While you are deploying a `POD` it's going through `phases`

> `Pending`
>   The Pod has been accepted by the Kubernetes system, but one or more of the Container images has not been created. This includes time before being scheduled as well as time spent downloading images over the network, which could take a while.
>
> `Running`
>   The Pod has been bound to a node, and all of the Containers have been created. At least one Container is still running, or is in the process of starting or restarting.
>
> `Succeeded`
>   All Containers in the Pod have terminated in success, and will not be restarted.
>
> `Failed`
>   All Containers in the Pod have terminated, and at least one Container has terminated in failure. That is, the Container either exited with non-zero status or was terminated by the system.
>
> `Unknown`
>   For some reason the state of the Pod could not be obtained, typically due to an error in communicating with the 
>   host of the Pod.

As for [Pod Conditions](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-conditions) it have a `type` which can have following values:

> - `PodScheduled`: the Pod has been scheduled to a node;
> - `Ready`: the Pod is able to serve requests and should be added to the load balancing pools of all matching Services;
> - `Initialized`: all  [init containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers)  have started successfully;
> - `Unschedulable`: the scheduler cannot schedule the Pod right now, for example due to lacking of resources or other constraints;
> - `ContainersReady`: all containers in the Pod are ready.

Please refer to the documentation regarding [Pod Lifecycle](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/) for more information.

When you are deploying your `POD`, you have to consider how many containers will be running in it.
The image will have to be downloaded, depending on the size it might take longer. Also default pull policy is `IfNotPresent`, which means that Kubernetes will skip the image pull if it already exists.
You can find more about [Updating Images](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#updating-images) can be found [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/).

You also need to consider how much resources your `Master` and `Node` has.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know this information. My question is when I create a pod either with one container or more is there any way to know how long it take to create this pod ( or container in case it has only one container) ?

Comment: No, Kubernetes cannot estimate how long will it take. It can tell you when it's ready. Or if you prep your own docker image and setup custom echo command to forward to stdout what was done.

Comment: we not talkings about application levels because kubernetes is not working in application level. But there are monitoring tools can tell you how long it takes to create a new pod. Or it might be a command can have information about the time takes to create a pod. For example there is a command tell you many information about the pod but not the time takes to create pod this command is kubectl describe pods. I need something like this command tell me how long it take to create a pod.

Comment: I did not heard about any monitoring tools that would tell you how long it takes for a pod to be created, that kind of metrics are not existing. There is no way of knowing how long will your server will be booting up for.

Comment: The original question was how to _estimate_ the start time of a pod. Cloud we just use the pod events difference of  `PodScheduled` and `Ready` running pod describe? The estimate of start time can be useful for many situations including setting up startup probes.

Comment: Sam, I imagine that would depend a lot on whether the image needs to be pulled.  Since pods may also have health checks before they are 'Ready', it can depend a lot on the images themselves.  Request -> Scheduled (assuming resources are available) and Scheduled -> Initialized (assuming image available on node) do seem to me like reasonable questions though.